# duvida de Lógica em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lógica

sou iniciante no mundo da programação e também em python.

Resolvendo alguns exercícios me deparei com este

> Faça um Programa para uma loja de tintas. O programa deverá pedir o tamanho em metros quadrados da área a ser pintada. Considere que a cobertura da tinta é de 1 litro para cada 6 metros quadrados e que a tinta é vendida em latas de 18 litros, que custam R$ 80,00 ou em galões de 3,6 litros, que custam R$ 25,00.
> Informe ao usuário as quantidades de tinta a serem compradas e os respectivos preços em 3 situações:
> comprar apenas latas de 18 litros;
> comprar apenas galões de 3,6 litros;
> misturar latas e galões, de forma que o desperdício de tinta seja menor. Acrescente 10% de folga e sempre arredonde os valores para cima, isto é, considere latas cheias.

Minha resolução funciona, chego no resultado esperado, porém a logica que utilizei estou achando muito extensa. como poderia resolver esta questão de forma mais eficiente?
segue abaixo o código.
Desde já agradeço.

```
import math

m2 = float(input('informe a quantidade de METRO QUADRADO (m²) a ser pintado: '))
consumo_litro = m2 / 6
print('\no consumo de tinta é: {:.2f} LITROS\n'.format(consumo_litro))
qtd_latas18 = consumo_litro / 18
qtd_latas36 = consumo_litro / 3.6
print('a quantidade de GALOES de 18 LITROS a ser usado é: {}'.format(math.ceil(qtd_latas18)))
print('a quantidade de LATAS de 3,6 LITROS a ser usado é: {}\n'.format(math.ceil(qtd_latas36)))
valor_total18 = math.ceil(qtd_latas18) * 80
valor_total36 = math.ceil(qtd_latas36) * 25
print('o valor total em GALOES de 18 LITROS é: R${}'.format(valor_total18))
print('o valor total em LATAS de 3,6 LITROS é: R$ {}\n'.format(valor_total36))
print('considerando o menor desperdíciode tinta, temos: \n')

qtd_latas_mistas18 = ((consumo_litro * 0.10) + consumo_litro) / 18
qtd_litros18 = math.trunc(qtd_latas_mistas18) * 18
resto18 = ((consumo_litro * 0.10) + consumo_litro) - qtd_litros18
qtd_latas_mistas36 = resto18 / 3.6
qtd_latas_mistas_total = math.trunc(qtd_latas_mistas18) + math.ceil(qtd_latas_mistas36)
valor_misto18 = math.trunc(qtd_latas_mistas18) * 80
valor_misto36 = math.ceil(qtd_latas_mistas36) * 25
total_misto = valor_misto18 + valor_misto36

print('quantidade de latas de 18 litros: {}'.format(math.trunc(qtd_latas_mistas18)))
print('qtd latas de 3,6: {}'.format(math.ceil(qtd_latas_mistas36)))
print('qtd latas mistas: {}'.format(qtd_latas_mistas_total))
print('\no valor total considerando GALOES e LATAS é (acresentando 10% de quebra): R$ {}'.format(total_misto))
```

Comment: Um engano que notei é que você considera os 10% de folga apenas para o cálculo de latas mistas quando deveria considerar para todas as situações. Para facilitar considere a área a ser pintada acrescida de 10%. Um operador que facilitaria seu cálculo na opção mista é o resto da divisão (%). Poderia eliminar algumas variáveis intermediárias mas com o tempo de prática de programação irá identificar estas situações.

Comment: seu código não está ruim, está bem escrito os nomes das variáveis, mas o bom é você não posta todo ele, já que é trabalho da faculdade, vem outro e copia seu trabalho e ainda corre o risco do seu professor acha seu código aqui.

Comment: Outra coisa: A **lata** tem 18 l e o **galão** 3.6 l. Na impressão você escreve ao contrário.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda de todos. @Marco Souza na verdade não estou fazendo faculdade. resolvi aprender programação e estou realizando alguns exercícios da internet

Comment: Por questão de organização, seria bom separar o código em funções, simplificando as partes, isso também irá ajudar a reutilizar algumas dessas partes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeira coisa que salta aos olhos é a quantidade de [números mágicos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_m%C3%A1gico_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_sistemas)). Eu transformei tudo em constantes (que na verdade não são constantes, são apenas variáveis com nome em caixa alta). Isso aumenta a legibilidade do código e facilita futuras alterações.

Note que a margem de segurança é `1.1`, não `0.1`, pois vai facilitar um pouquinho a conta a seguir.

```py
M2_POR_LITRO = 6
PRECO_GALAO = 80
LITROS_GALAO = 18
PRECO_LATA = 25
LITROS_LATA = 3.6
MARGEM_SEGURANCA = 1.1
```

Depois disso, eu pego o input do usuário exatamente como tu fez, mas já adiciono a margem de segurança ali mesmo, pois, na minha interpretação do enunciado do problema essa margem deve ser aplicada a todas as situações, não apenas à terceira.

```py
m2 = float(input('informe a quantidade de METRO QUADRADO (m²) a ser pintado: '))

consumo_litro = m2 / M2_POR_LITRO * MARGEM_SEGURANCA
```

Seguindo em frente, chegu a hora de processar os dados.

Resolvi fazer as contas antes de printar os resultados. Isso não muda em nada o output do programa pro usuário, mas deixa o código separado em "blocos lógicos": primeiro o input, depois o processamento, por último o output. Tenho a opinião de que isso torna o fluxo do código mais claro.

Perceba que simplifiquei o cálculo das tintas mistas, tirei proveito do [operador `//`, às vezes chamado de integer division](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

```py
qtd_galao_apenas = math.ceil(consumo_litro / LITROS_GALAO)
valor_galao_apenas = qtd_galao_apenas * PRECO_GALAO

qtd_lata_apenas = math.ceil(consumo_litro / LITROS_LATA)
valor_lata_apenas = qtd_lata_apenas * PRECO_LATA

qtd_galao_misto = consumo_litro // LITROS_GALAO
qtd_lata_misto = math.ceil((consumo_litro - qtd_galao_misto * LITROS_GALAO) / LITROS_LATA)
valor_galao_misto = qtd_galao_misto * PRECO_GALAO
valor_lata_misto = qtd_lata_misto * PRECO_LATA
```

Pra finalizar, printei todos os resultados na tela.

A maior diferença pro teu código é que [eu usei as f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) em vez do método `format`.

Outra diferença é que eu usei vários comandos `print()` pra gerar linha em branco em vez de colocar o `\n` dentro das strings. Sinto que isso torna o código mais fácil de ser entendido, pois fica muito parecido com o output na prática. Essa é uma questão puramente de gosto e tu pode seguir colocando os `\n` pra gerar linhas em branco sem problema algum.

```py
print()
print(f'o consumo de tinta é: {consumo_litro:.2f} LITROS')
print()
print(f'a quantidade de GALOES de 18 LITROS a ser usado é: {qtd_galao_apenas:.0f}')
print(f'o valor total em GALOES de 18 LITROS é: R$ {valor_galao_apenas:.2f}')
print()
print(f'a quantidade de LATAS de 3,6 LITROS a ser usado é: {qtd_lata_apenas:.0f}')
print(f'o valor total em LATAS de 3,6 LITROS é: R$ {valor_lata_apenas:.2f}')
print()
print('considerando o menor desperdíciode tinta, temos:')
print(f'quantidade galões: {qtd_galao_misto:.0f}')
print(f'quantidade latas: {qtd_lata_misto:.0f}')
print(f'quantidade total mistas: {qtd_galao_misto + qtd_lata_misto:.0f}')
print(f'valor total considerando GALOES e LATAS é: R$ {valor_galao_misto + valor_lata_misto:.2f}')
```

O passo seguinte seria quebrar o programa em várias funções, e eu te encorajo a fazer isso daqui pra frente, especialmente em programas mais longos.

Comment: Gabriel, muito obrigado pela explicação. vejo que estou no caminho certo, mas ainda tenho muito pela frente! 
é bom ver outras maneiras de resolver o mesmo problema, pois assim tenho como adquirir mais experiencia com outras resoluções, da questão. 
Ajudou bastante. Obrigado.