# Dúvida em lógica de exercício de Python (Iniciante)

Tags: python, python-3.x, lógica

Olá, comecei recentemente meu estudo em Lógica de Programação em Python. Tenho uma pequena base em C. Me deparei com um exercício na internet no qual diz o seguinte:

"Faça um Programa para uma loja de tintas. O programa deverá pedir o tamanho em metros quadrados da área a ser pintada. Considere que a cobertura da tinta é de 1 litro para cada 6 metros quadrados e que a tinta é vendida em latas de 18 litros, que custam R$ 80,00 ou em galões de 3,6 litros, que custam R$ 25,00.
Informe ao usuário as quantidades de tinta a serem compradas e os respectivos preços em 3 situações:

- comprar apenas latas de 18 litros;
- comprar apenas galões de 3,6 litros;
- misturar latas e galões, de forma que o desperdício de tinta seja menor. Acrescente 10% de folga e sempre arredonde os valores para cima, isto é, considere latas cheias."

O problema é que eu cheguei no terceiro cenário e não consegui desenvolver o pensamento correto de como deveria fazer para calcular a forma de maior custo x benefício. Alguém poderia dar uma dica e informar se a lógica que eu tô seguindo está correta ?

Código:

```
metros = float(input("Informe os m²: "))
litros = metros/6
if(metros%108 > 0 and metros%21.6>0): 
latas = metros//108
latas = latas + 1
preçol = latas * 80
galao = metros//21.6
galao = galao + 1
preçog = galao * 25
print("Você vai precisar de: {} latas de 18L e vai gastar {} reais".format(latas,preçol))
else:
latas = metros/108
preçol = latas * 80
galao = metros/21.6
preçog = galao * 25
print("Você vai precisar apenas de {} latas de 18L e vai gastar {} reais".format(latas,preçol))
print("Você vai precisar apenas de {} galao de 3,6L e vai gastar {} reais".format(galao,preçog))
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu bati cabeça pra resolver esse problema tbm. Mas eu consegui resolver

De inicio, fiz a funcao do calculo, onde eu declaro algumas variaveis base como o preco e o tamanho das latas/galoes.

Apos isso, declarei outra variavel pra receber o valor do litro total passado pelo user, divido pelo tamanho das latas/galoes para ter o valor de maximo de latas serao necessarias e com uma condicionante adicionada, se caso o valor der diferente de 0 ( ou seja, a quantia de latas e menor do que o que e preciso), onde esse resultado do restante da divisao (%) e feito com os galoes de 3,6L.

segue abaixo o codigo:

```
def calculo_loja_tintas(litro):
    # LATAS
    latas = litro / 18
    if latas % 18 != 0:
        latas += 1
    preco_das_latas= latas * 80

    # GALOES
    galoes = litro / 3.6
    if galoes % 3.6 != 0:
        galoes += 1
    preco_dos_galoes = galoes * 25

    mistura_lata = int(litro / 18.0)
    mistura_galao = int((litro - (mistura_lata * 18)) / 3.6)
    if litro - (mistura_lata * 18) % 3.6 != 0:
        mistura_galao += 1
    galoes_total = (mistura_lata * 80) + (mistura_galao * 25)


    print(f'''
        Total de Litros necessário para pintar: {litro:.0f}L
        Apenas latas de 18 litros: {latas:.0f} Und. - Preço: R$ {preco_das_latas:.2f}
        Apenas galões de 3.6 litros: {galoes:.0f} Und. - Preço: R$ {preco_dos_galoes:.2f}
        Mistura: {mistura_lata:.0f} Latas e {mistura_galao:.0f} Galões = 
        R$ {galoes_total:.2f}''')

area_pintura = float(input('Tamanho em metros quadrados da área a ser pintada: '))
litros = area_pintura / 6  * 1.1
calculo_loja_tintas(litros)
```

Gosto de declarar variaveis completos, para melhor leitura.
Nao sou muito bom em explicar muitas coisas, mas se caso tiver alguma duvida ainda sobre, comenta ai que eu tento te ajudar dnv.

Obrigado e bons estudos.

@edit:
Existeuma pergunta com o mesmo problema, caso tu quiser outra forma de resolver o exercicio:
[Clique Aqui para ser direcionado para o post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/484121/duvida-de-l%C3%B3gica-em-python?rq=1)